# Python Pandas merging 2 tables with inner join:

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am merging two tables with an inner join using pandas but I am getting a weird output. Below I am pasting the two tables:
[image]

[image]

I want to inner join the tables so it only shows the zipcodes in the df2 table so I use this line:

result = pd.merge(ppy, df2, how="inner", on=["zipcode"])

But now I am getting two records for each zipcode

[image]

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this or what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Your `rent earned per year` column is having different value that's why

Comment: you have duplicate keys so you're creating a cartesian product of your dataframe, you need `isin` `ppy.loc[ppy['zipcode'].isin(df2['zipcode'].tolist()]`

Answer (score 1):

The data types of zipcode variables in datasets can be different. Check it with the dtype () method. If the data types are different, you can combine them and combine them.